# SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (RO_MARGE_TABLE_PK) violated

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I don't know why I am getting SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (RO_MARGE_TABLE_PK) violated

My SQL statement is:

```
insert into RO_MARGE_TABLE ( PROMOTION_OFFER_ID, PROMOTION_CODE,  
SYS_CREATION_DATE, SYS_UPDATE_DATE, OPERATOR_ID, APPLICATION_ID,     
DL_SERVICE_CODE, DL_UPDATE_STAMP, SPEED, PREMIUM_TIERS, PACKAGE_TYPE,    
EFFECTIVE_DATE, EXPIRATION_DATE, PROMOTION_AMOUNT) 
select PROMOTION_OFFER_ID, 
DECODE(PROMOTION_CODE,NULL,NULL,NVL(RTRIM(PROMOTION_CODE),' ')), 
SYS_CREATION_DATE, SYS_UPDATE_DATE, OPERATOR_ID, 
DECODE(APPLICATION_ID,NULL,NULL,NVL(RTRIM(APPLICATION_ID),' ')), 
DECODE(DL_SERVICE_CODE,NULL,NULL,NVL(RTRIM(DL_SERVICE_CODE),' ')),  
DL_UPDATE_STAMP, DECODE(SPEED,NULL,NULL,NVL(RTRIM(SPEED),' ')), 
DECODE(PREMIUM_TIERS,NULL,NULL,NVL(RTRIM(PREMIUM_TIERS),' ')), 
DECODE(PACKAGE_TYPE,NULL,NULL,NVL(RTRIM(PACKAGE_TYPE),' ')), 
EFFECTIVE_DATE, EXPIRATION_DATE, PROMOTION_AMOUNT 
FROM SCHEMT098.MARGE_TABLE@DBLINK865;
```

and I'm getting: `SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (RO_MARGE_TABLE_PK) violated`

Comment: The error is fairly clear, but it will help if you post a small sample of the target table and the info to be inserted.

Comment: Well, from the looks of it, you're violating a unique constraint..

Comment: Thank you  Mike for  your  quick responce.....i found  that  the  source  has  duplicates  Primary  keys which  causes  issues

Comment: Thank  you again  Stidgeon...i  really  appreciate  spending time  answering.I finally  found source  has  duplicates  keys

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that PROMOTION_OFFER_ID is the primary key on this table based off the columns you are selecting to insert into RO_MARGE_TABLE. Based off your error, I bet you are trying to insert a PROMOTION_OFFER_ID that already exist in the table RO_MARGE_TABLE.

Comment: Thank you  Cannon......i found  that  the  source  has  duplicates  Primary  keys.Tagert was  empty at that time